# Changes in other elements based on listbox selections in threepenny-gui

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

So I have a simple example layout with a listbox, a button and a textarea, where clicking the button changes the text in the textarea:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe

import qualified Graphics.UI.Threepenny as UI
import Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core

main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup w = do
    return w # set UI.title "Simple example"

    listBox     <- UI.listBox   (pure ["First", "Second"]) (pure Nothing) ((UI.string .) <$> (pure id))
    button      <- UI.button    # set UI.text "Button"
    display     <- UI.textarea  # set UI.text "Initial value"

    element listBox # set (attr "size") "10"    

    getBody w   #+ [element listBox, element button, element display]

    on UI.click button $ const $ do
        element display # set UI.text "new text"
```

What I wanted to do is have the change be dependent on the listbox selection (for example have the `"new text"` be `"First"` or `"Second"` based on the selection).

I can quite easily get the selection by combining `userSelection` and `facts` as

```
facts . userSelection :: ListBox a -> Behavior (Maybe a)
```

but because setting the value for the textarea is done with

```
set text :: String -> UI Element -> UI Element
```

I don't know how to work around the fact that the selection is a `Behavior`.

All this seems a bit unidiomatic to me and I was wondering what would be the correct way to do this. Maybe I should do something already when the listbox selection is done or changed and not only when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there was [a regression](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/issues/109) which affected the code here. That issue is now solved. Threepenny 0.6.0.3 has a temporary fix, and the definitive one will be included in the release after that.

---

The code in the [pastebin you provided](http://pastebin.com/D97sFUuA) is almost correct. The only needed change is that you don't need to use `sink` within the button click callback - in your case, `sink` should establish a permanent connection between a behavior and the content of the text area, with the behavior value changing in response to the button click events.

For the sake of completeness, here is a full solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe

import qualified Graphics.UI.Threepenny as UI
import Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core

main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup w = void $ mdo
    return w # set UI.title "Simple example"

    listBox <- UI.listBox
        (pure ["First", "Second"]) bSelected (pure $ UI.string)
    button  <- UI.button # set UI.text "Button"
    display <- UI.textarea

    element listBox # set (attr "size") "10"

    getBody w #+ [element listBox, element button, element display]

    bSelected <- stepper Nothing $ rumors (UI.userSelection listBox)
    let eClick = UI.click button
        eValue = fromMaybe "No selection" <$> bSelected <@ eClick
    bValue    <- stepper "Initial value" eValue

    element display # sink UI.text bValue
```

The two key things to take away are:

- The `Behavior (Maybe a)` argument to `listBox` does not set just the initial selected value, but determines the evolution of the value throughout the lifetime of the application. In this example, `facts $ UI.userSelection listBox` is just `bSelected`, as can be verified through [the source code of the `Widgets` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.2/docs/src/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Widgets.html#listBox).
- The typical way to sample a behavior on event occurrences is through `(<@)` (or `<@>` if the event carries data you wish to make use of).

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up trying many different things, but with the same (non-existent) results. Your example code didn't indeed work with Threepenny 0.6, but going back to Threepenny 0.5 has solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Caution*: I am not familiar with ThreePenny, I'm just reading the documentation.

I think you need to `sink` your listbox into your text area:

```
element display # sink UI.text ((maybe "new text" id) <$> (facts $ userSelection listBox))
```

Comment: Thanks, now that i found `sink`, the whole question looks a bit stupid. Got the program to work though (although the listbox selection doesn't actually change and I'm only reading the `facts`-part of `userSelection`).

Comment: I don't know how many people will read this anymore, but I'm still having a hard time making the actual change happen. I'm pretty sure the `rumors` of `userSelection` should be read somewhere and the `facts` changed accordingly but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a stepper for the listbox and then just sink to display

```
listB <- stepper Nothing (userSelection listBox)
element display # sink UI.text ((maybe "new text" id) <$> (listB)
```

Then if you want to sample the behavior with the button

```
listB <- stepper Nothing (userSelection listBox)
button      <- UI.button    # set UI.text "Button"
cutedListB <- stepper Nothing (listB <@ UI.click button)
element display # sink UI.text ((maybe "new text" id) <$> (listB)
```

Comment: Well, first the types in `stepper Nothing (userSelection listBox)` don't match (I tried `stepper Nothing (rumors $ userSelection listBox)`). I still can't get anything to happen, even with just http://pastebin.com/D97sFUuA (the value changes when clicking the button, but always to "new text").

Comment: There really is something I don't understand about these `Tidings` and `Behavior` -things as I can't get this to work.

Comment: Tidings is just a combination of behavior and event. It's usefull when you need to sample two or more events and behaviors using the applicative instance defined for tidings . Your fix adding rumors is right.  Maybe you are hitting the bug that i reported on github and duplode suggests in his answer.